One Specific Breakpoint is not being hit on an event Invoke
I have the following code in a State Management Service: DocumentStateService
public async Task AddSection(DocumentView document, SectionView newSection)
{
    try
    {
        var sectionId = await this.SectionProcessingService.AddSectionAsync(document, newSection);
        this.OnSectionAdd?.Invoke(sectionId);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}

By realizing that my view is not being updated, I put two breakpoints on both:
        var sectionId = await this.SectionProcessingService.AddSectionAsync(document, newSection);
        this.OnSectionAdd?.Invoke(sectionId);

For some reason, The first breakpoint (reaching the AddSectionAsync method is being hit but the this.OnSectionAdd?.Invoke(sectionId); is not. Why?
To further explain things:

I registered the Management service as scoped.
Injected it in my view component
used Subscription in OnInitializedAsync by DocumentStateService.OnSectionAdd += HandleAddSection; 
Handled the event.


My guess is await this.SectionProcessingService.AddSectionAsync(document, newSection); never returns.  Put a dummy line [something like var x = sectionId] in between the two to see what sectionId is.
